# how to take Checkout to previous commit in SVN in Xcode 4.2

Tags: svn, ios5, xcode4.2

Hi I am a little new to SVN and Xcode so dose not know much stuff,
I am working on Xcode 4.2, i was developing a project and commited to SVN then my friend took the checkout of my code , he then made changes to them and again commited to SVN but his code was buggy and i was not knowing this, and i too updated my project with his, this resulted in both having the buggy copy.
I need to know how to take the checkout of old commit that was not buggy i.e>

1. i made commit (good copy) version 4990
2. friend too checkout and edited and then commited.( Error in his files )version 5000
3. I updated my code to the one he commited (error in my project as well).version 5005

   Now i wanna have the checkout of the version i commited i.e> the 1st one the version 4990.

Kindly tell me how to do it in Xcode or if through Terminal then the complete procedure not just the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there's no way to do this in `XCode`, but I'll advise you to use Tortoise SVN to do this.

Tortoise Repository: http://scplugin.tigris.org/

The Mac Installer installs a Program in your Program Folder, which you can drag onto your Finder Toolbar. If you now select a Folder, you are able to click the Icon and get a list of the SVN commands.

Comment: well yup its not possible in Xcode but We can use eclipse to take the previous checkout and work further but would not be able to commit back again using xcode. Thus for the trial purpose we can use eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

May help you simply use below command:

```
svn checkout -r YOUR_REVISION NUMBER  PATH
```

Example:

```
svn checkout -r 15 https://xyz.com/ApplicationName
```

Comment: Lack of up votes is surprising. Although it's not possible to checkout a specific revision using Xcode, you can indeed use the above mentioned Terminal command to get the required results. Thanks.